# How to fill a typescript class model in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a class model and I don't know how to fill a class with values.

**User.ts**

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        username: string,
        password: string,
        token: string
    ) { }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {

    let user = new User('uname' , 'pword', 'sampletoken');
    console.log(user);
  }
```

When I run this, the user is still empty.

[image]

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **access specifiers** to constructor arguments for making it as a class property. Otherwise it will be considered as, properties in constructor method scope only.

**User.ts**

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public username: string,
        public password: string,
        public token: string
    ) { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The alternate way is you can also do this way :-

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';

  constructor(){
     let user = new User({username: 'abc', password: '1234', token: 1});
     console.log(user);

  }
}


    class User {
        public username?: string;
        public password?: string;
        public token?: number;

        constructor(values: User) {
          Object.assign(this, values);
        }
    }
```

Here is the link you can check it in console..
[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-7t38p?fontsize=14)

Comment: This is the cleanest solution! The verbose approach of passing an object to the constructor, coupled with not having to repetitiously assign every property within the constructor makes this the most scalable and desirable solution in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgot to add variables and assign them in constructor:

```
export class User {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    token: string;

    constructor(username: string,
                password: string,
                token: string) {
         this.username = username;
         this.password= password;
         this.token= token;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-woqfxe?embed=1&file=src/app/User.ts)**

```
export class User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  token: string;
  constructor(username: string, password: string, token: string) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password; 
    this.token = token;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show you with an example how you can use one class in angular.

**items.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Items {
  items: Item[] = [];

  defaultItem: any = {
    "name": "Burt Bear",
    "profilePic": "assets/img/speakers/bear.jpg",
    "about": "Burt is a Bear.",
  };


  constructor(public name: string) {
    let items = [
      {
        "name": "Burt Bear",
        "profilePic": "assets/img/speakers/bear.jpg",
        "about": "Burt is a Bear."
      }
    ];

  }

}
```

lets check how to grab these data

**item-details.ts**

```
import { Items } from '../../providers';

export class ItemDetailPage {
  item: any;

  constructor(items: Items) {
    this.item =  items.defaultItem;
  }

}
```